# Error The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server when run sub folder in zend 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, zend-framework2

I have a project in `www/zendtest`

This is my folders structure:
[image: Struct]

Contents of `www/zendtest/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Contents of `www/zendtest/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

When I run http://localhost/zendtest the result is the following error:

```
404 Page Not Found
The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server.
```

How do I avoid having the `/public/` folder name so that I can run this on the domain `localhost/zendtest`?

Comment: I think what you want to do ideally, is set up a virtual host in apache. See here: https://serversforhackers.com/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: Also, I think that `localhost/zendtest` should be loading `www/zendtest/public/`, the way that you have it at the moment is that it is loading `www/zendtest/` which will cause you endless grief. Take a look at virtual hosts at it seems that you are using something like WAMP it will be helpful for you. If you create a virtual host config then set a fake domain in your hosts file like `127.0.0.1 zend.dev` then you would be able to load `http://zend.dev` in the browser which actually loads the index of the directory: `www/zendtest/public/`. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because of the following:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

You have the directory `www` to be your `DocumentRoot`. When you rewrite the URL's to `/public/index.php`, Apache is trying to search for `www/public/index.php` file, which of course, does not exist.

Use a `RewriteBase` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zendtest/

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/zendtest/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zendtest/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```